# Parameterise database name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have scripts to deploy across multiple environments (DEV, SIT ,UAT etc) that have different database names in each environment i.e. foobar1, foobar2 etc.

Is there a way to parametrize the db name within `USE [database]` to avoid having 1 script per environment? The code below fails at `@dbname`

```
DECLARE @dbname NVARCHAR(10)

SET @dbname = (SELECT NAME 
               FROM sys.databases                   
               WHERE NAME LIKE 'foobar%')

USE @dbname

GO
```

Comment: I've added the T-sql tag because it looks like T_SQL... but it could be Sybase. Please tag the actual database technology as solutions will differ

Comment: You could try using SQLCMD mode (again SQL Server). You can use variable placeholders here but you can't dynamically derive them. You can dynamically create anothe .SQL file and run it though.See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_server_appendix_z/archive/2013/02/23/sql-server-management-studio-sqlcmd-meets-the-richter-scale.aspx

Comment: thanks Nick, i've added the sql-server tag

Comment: if it were me, I'd just remove the USE database from the scripts, you don't need that if you run the scripts in the context of the database and leaving that out keeps it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments also suggest, you have a couple of options here.

1. Use SQLCMD mode. In SQL Management studio you'll find this (when you have a query open) in the menu [Query] -> [SQLCMD Mode].
   Then in your script you can use:

   ```
   :SETVAR DatabaseName “AdventureWorks2012″
   USE $(DatabaseName);
   ```

For more information see http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/06/28/sql-server-how-to-set-variable-and-use-variable-in-sqlcmd-mode/

2. Use a placeholder. E.g. you use `##DATABASENAME##`, and you find/replace it to the correct name.

   ```
   USE [##DATABASENAME##];
   ```
3. Don't use the `USE` statement, and select the correct database when you want to execute the script.
4. Use Dynamic SQL (a bit of overkill here). Your query will become a giant string in which you can use variables.

   ```
   declare @databasename nvarchar(100) = 'YourDatabaseName';
   declare @sqlStringToExecute nvarchar(max);

   set @sqlStringToExecute = 'Use ' + @databasename + '; -- do rest of the query'

   EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlStringToExecute
   ```